# solr cloud IOException talking to Server

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am trying to implemented solr cloud followed steps from `http://myjeeva.com/solrcloud-cluster-single-collection-deployment.html` .

Steps I follow:
created 3 node i.e. external zokkepre and its working fine.one is leader and other two are followers.
I deploy solr to tomcat and other configuration as mentioned in blog post.
After sucessfully deploying solr on tomcat I tried to create shrads but it gives error like

```
prashant@prashant-desktop:~$ curl 'http://localhost:7070/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=profiles&numShards=5&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=5'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">16623</int></lst><lst name="failure"><str>org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr1.example.org:9090/solr</str><str>org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr1.example.org:7070/solr</str><str>org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr1.example.org:9090/solr</str><str>org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr1.example.org:7070/solr</str><str>org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr1.example.org:9090/solr</str><str>org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr1.example.org:9090/solr</str><str>org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr1.example.org:7070/solr</str><str>org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr1.example.org:7070/solr</str><str>org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr1.example.org:7070/solr</str><str>org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr1.example.org:9090/solr</str></lst>
</response>
```

Where I am missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question in the end? Thanks